# Efficient byte[] to BitmapImage and vice versa conversion in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, arrays

I need to get the BitmapImage from the byte array. Currently I'm working with MemoryStream 
(byte[] -> MemoryStream -> BitmapImage) but it seems to be not efficient. 
The same situation in the other way round - I need to get the byte array representing the BitmapFrame. Again, I'm doing that with MemoryStream.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish that task? Is it possible to speedup the conversion?

Thank you in advance for the replies and hints!

Cheers

Comment: What leads you to believe that the MemoryStream method is inefficient?

Comment: I actually observe it is rather slow - I search for the most efficient one.

Comment: And what about byte[] as backing end for the bitmap object?

Comment: I think he means that reading the byte array might be the costly part, depending on where you read it from. The memory stream does incur a bit of extra overhead as opposed to getting the stream directly from the source, but there shouldn't be any noticeable delays unless you work with really large images. Try to benchmark only the code that creates the bitmap and see how long that takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using BitmapSource.CopyPixels to extract the bytes from the BitmapSource and then BitmapSource.Create to create a new image from the byte array.

I'm not sure how effective it is though, but it is sufficient for my purposes (I can extract the pixels, recolor them and then paste them back on a 2000*2000 image with barely noticeable delay).